# RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING equivalent for Java

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, rsa

Currently i use the encryption instance in Java like this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

But i cannot decrypt my encrypted message in OpenSSL where i want to use RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING.
What do i need to add to the `"RSA"` to be able to use the RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING?

Please help

Comment: "RSA" is a shorthand for "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding" if I'm not mistaken. In general, these shorthand notations should be avoided, they only add confusion nd therefore make code less maintainable.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using "RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding" in `getInstance()`?

Otherwise, take a look at [Java Cryptography Architecture Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) to find a list of possible parameters.

Comment: This not working. I am unable to decrypt messages encrypted with ursa in node.js.

Comment: Maybe "OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding" ?